# I'm trying to delete the pictures in the gallery in android app using the Jobscheduler, but I can't delete them

Tags: android

I'm creating an Android app that manages screenshot folders in the gallery.
One of the functions of the app is to automatically delete screenshot images, and to do this, I created two classes: `DeleteActivity` and `MyJobService`. `MyJobService` class is doing background work with `JobScheduler`.So I'm going to send `uri` from the `DeleteActivity` class to `MyJobService` class and delete pictures from the screenshot folder with the `uri`, but this is the code I've worked on so far, but there's no error, and nothing happens. What's the problem? Is there a way to automatically delete pictures other than using `uri`? Please let me know if there's a good way.

DeleteAcitivity.class

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int READ_REQUEST_CODE = 42;
    private static final int JOB_REQUEST_CODE = 43;
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
    private static final int DELETE_JOB_KEY = 123;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("LastSetting", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        final int spinnerSelected = sharedPreferences.getInt("LastClick", 0);
        final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        final View txt1 = findViewById(R.id.txt1);
        final View txt2 = findViewById(R.id.txt2);

        final SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        boolean silent = settings.getBoolean("switchkey", false);


        Switch deleteSwitch = findViewById(R.id.switchdel);
        deleteSwitch.setChecked(silent);
        deleteSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    txt1.setEnabled(true);
                    spinner.setEnabled(true);
                    txt2.setEnabled(true);

                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, JOB_REQUEST_CODE);


                } else {
                    txt1.setEnabled(false);
                    spinner.setEnabled(false);
                    txt2.setEnabled(false);

                    JobScheduler scheduler = (JobScheduler) getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
                    scheduler.cancel(DELETE_JOB_KEY);
                    Log.d(TAG, "Job cancelled");

                }

                SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("switchkey", isChecked).commit();

            }
        });


        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.days_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setSelection(spinnerSelected);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                editor.putInt("LastClick", position).commit();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

        String txtSpinner = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

        Button picture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnfind);
        picture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {  
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(intent, READ_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        });


    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent resultData) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, resultData);
        if (requestCode == READ_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            try {
                Uri uri = null;
                if (resultData != null) {
                    uri = resultData.getData();
                }

                Bitmap img = getBitmapFromUri(uri);
                DocumentsContract.deleteDocument(getContentResolver(), uri);
            }  // try

            catch (Exception e) {
            } // catch
        } // if

        if(requestCode == JOB_REQUEST_CODE)
        {
            if(resultData != null) {
                ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(MainActivity.this, MyJobService.class);
                PersistableBundle bundle = new PersistableBundle();
                bundle.putString("imageUri", resultData.getData().toString());
                JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo.Builder(DELETE_JOB_KEY, componentName)
                        .setExtras(bundle)
                        .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY)
                        .setPersisted(true)
                        .setPeriodic(15 * 60 * 1000);

                JobScheduler scheduler = (JobScheduler) getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
                scheduler.schedule(builder.build());
            }
        }

    } // onActivityResult()


    private Bitmap getBitmapFromUri(Uri uri) throws IOException {
        ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor =
                getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
        FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();
        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor);
        parcelFileDescriptor.close();
        return image;
    }



}
```

MyJobService.class

```
 public class MyJobService extends JobService {
 private static final String TAG = "MyJobService";
 private boolean jobCancelled = false;
 private JobParameters jobParameters;
 private DeleteAsyncTask deleteAsyncTask;


 @Override
 public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {

     this.jobParameters = params;
     PersistableBundle persistableBundle = params.getExtras();
     String strUri = persistableBundle.getString("imageUri");
     Uri uri = Uri.parse(strUri);
     deleteAsyncTask = (DeleteAsyncTask) new DeleteAsyncTask().execute(uri);
     return true;

 }


 @Override
 public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
     Log.d(TAG, "onStopJob: Job cancelled before completion");
     if(null != deleteAsyncTask){
         if(!deleteAsyncTask.isCancelled())
             deleteAsyncTask.cancel(true);
     }
     return true;
 }

 private class DeleteAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Uri, Integer, String>{

     @Override
     protected String doInBackground(Uri... uris) {
         try {
             DocumentsContract.deleteDocument(getContentResolver(), uris[0]);
         } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }

         return "Job Finished!";
     }

     @Override
     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values){
         super.onProgressUpdate(values);

         Log.d(TAG, "onProgressUpdate: i was: " + values[0]);
     }


     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
         super.onPostExecute(s);

         Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecute: message: " + s);
         jobFinished(jobParameters, true);
     }

 }







}
```

Comment: `bundle.putString("imageUri", resultData.getData().toString());` resultData.getData().toString() is no uri. Impossible with the used camera intent. Please tell its value.

Comment: Further in your code -much too much-- there is nothing with screenshots.

Comment: You're right, because before I do it with the screenshot folder, I'm just working on the entire picture in the gallery, and then I'm going to do it with the screenshot folder pictures if that works, and I don't know if I can make this app as planned, and I don't know what to do if that code is wrong, but thank you for answering me and having a nice day.